# Do not escape html stored as string (execute or process html string)

Tags: php, html, escaping, echo

In PHP (Wordpress theme function, trying to add html stored in theme options to blog header),
I'm trying to get the following line:

```
$x="<p>html</p>"; echo $x;
```

To render html just like:

```
echo "<p>html</p>";
```

The results are different, the first one will display html tags while the second will process the html.
Can someone please help.
Thanks

Comment: They both render the same result : http://codepad.viper-7.com/vzRPxP

Comment: There's no functional difference between the two. PHP doesn't care if you echo out a fixed string or the contents of a variable - it does not "interpret" html.

Comment: you need it raw - filter marks the value as being "safe", which means that in an environment with automatic escaping enabled this variable will not be escaped if raw is the last filter applied to it. In your case because your framework environment escaped the string hence html tags are displayed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use single quotes

[Single quotes vs double quotes in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/difference-between-single-quote-and-double-quote-string-in-php)

```
echo '<p>HTML</p>';
```

Comment: I'm actually fetching the variable through another function  get_field(), I over simplified the example above I guess.

Answer (score 26):

A. If you want to show the HTML Tags you can just use `htmlentities`

Example

```
$x = "<p>html</p>";
echo htmlentities($x);
```

Output

```
<p>html</p>
```

B. If you want the other way round its possible your string is stored as  `&lt;p&gt;html&lt;/p&gt;` that is why you are seeing `<p>html</p>` then you should use `html_entity_decode`

Example

```
$x = "&lt;p&gt;html&lt;/p&gt;";
echo html_entity_decode($x);
```

Output

```
html
```

C. It could be you are not using a web broswer and you want `html` then you should use `strip_tags`

Example

```
$x = "<p>html</p>";
echo strip_tags($x);
```

Output

```
html
```

Comment: Sorry I'm looking for the other way around, I only need the output to be the text : html

Comment: can you `var_dump(get_field())` or where you are getting the info from let me see if you are getting the write string format

Comment: I got this: string(23) "<p>hh</p> "

Comment: if you `echo get_field()` you should get `hh` not `<p>hh</p>` if you are access it via a web browser

Comment: I'm still getting <p>hh</p> with the code: echo get_field("general_header_code", 'option'); even on the example you mentioned above on code pad, I'm getting different results

Comment: use `strip_tags` ans see the output ....

Comment: Still not working. Sorry. I'm still getting <p>s. The code I eventually want to output is actually google adsense code, so not sure about strip tags.

Comment: There is nothing you are doing wrong .. you can add your code to pastebin  let me see if i can help

Comment: Here is the full code http://pastebin.com/umQKXNN8 the otput when using var_dump is string(23) "<p>hh</p> "

Comment: It worked, appears to be a cache problem with custom fileds. Thank you for your time.