# How to show line break using PHP?

Tags: php

I am inserting this text `What is <br/> PHP?` into the database

Now I want to show this text as a line break. Like below:

> What is 
>  PHP?

I am using PHP nl2br() function but it's not working. I am getting the value like this:

```
What is <br/> PHP?
```

How can I solve it?

Thank You.

Comment: check what is inserted in data base may be html special character has been inserted?

Comment: In `What is <br/> PHP?` there's no new lines.

Comment: @ChetanAmeta in the database value is like this: `What is <br/> PHP?`

Comment: try this `$string  =  "What is <br/> PHP?";
echo htmlentities($string);` If you want to show `<br/>`

Comment: @SahilGulati then it's showing this: `What is &lt;br/&gt; PHP?`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do not escape html stored as string (execute or process html string)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12693093/do-not-escape-html-stored-as-string-execute-or-process-html-string)

Comment: You can use \n for new line.

Comment: @InspireShahin ok. I inserted the text with `\n` but when I show the text I am using `nl2br()` but still I can't see the line break.

Comment: @Shibbir Ahmed if you are storing `What is <br/> PHP?` and hope when you are fetching it and you will get the same value like: `What is <br/> PHP?` if this is so then i think you don't have to do any thing just like: `$string = "What is <br/> PHP?";
echo $string;` echo will read the <br> tag

Comment: @BunkerBoy  You right but then it's showing same: `What is <br/> PHP?`

Comment: @Shibbir Ahmed  `echo htmlspecialchars_decode($string);`

Comment: @BunkerBoy no luck :(

Comment: @Shibbir Ahmed update your question with exact value what you are getting from db

Comment: try using backslash n like this \n

Comment: @Kevin.a I used `\n` and `<br/>` when I insert the text into the database but when I showing it no line break. But using `\n` I see a line break in the source code only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A question comes up here... **where are you inserting this text (string) ?**

If you are injecting it as HTML you'll get the desired result in the rendered page.

I assume this is not the case: you want HTML line breaks turned into newlines.

**So...**

---

`nl2br()`converts newlines into `<br />`: that's the opposite you want to do

http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Just use `str_replace`:

```
$out = str_replace( "<br/>", "\n", $in );
```

Where `$in` is the input string and `$out` is the desired output

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Just a couple of things to note:

1) the above code will work with HTML line breaks `<br/>`, not if you have `<br>`, or `<br />`

If this is an issue you may pass the function array of strings and array of their replacements. This is well documented in the link above.

2) If you use the code snipped I wrote above you'll end having two spaces in the resulting string:

`What is`  (with trailing space)

`PHP` (with leading space)

Comment: "the above code will work with HTML line breaks <br/>, not if you have <br>, or <br />" ==> `<br>` **is** a html line break. you probably mean XHTML line break or something like that.

Comment: @Xatenev  you're right: I've made the code snippet using the HTML (XHTML) line break tag in the OP answer for simplicity. I take care to point out that line breaks may have different syntax (note nr. 1)

Answer (score 0):

Just use css instead of server-side transformations:

```css
p {
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

```html
<p>I am inserting this text What is 
               PHP? into the database
</p>

<p>Now I want to show this text as a line break. Like below:</p>

<p>What    is 
PHP?</p>
```